# Getting command line parameters in Lua interpreter

Tags: lua

How can I call a function in Lua?
I am new to Lua and couldn't find how to do something very simple. I write a test.lua and make it executable. Inside I put this:

```
function Double(n)
 return 2*n
end

print(Double(15))
```

If I call `test.lua`, it returns 30, ok.

Now I remove the `print` line and want to be able to call the function with something like:

```
test.lua 15
```

It doesn't work. How can I call the function from the command line or from the Lua shell without hard coding the first argument?

Comment: This has nothing to do with calling a function. You're talking about how you get parameters from the command line. You can't call a function from Lua's command line; you can get parameters and then decide what to do with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an argument to the script which will appear in the arg global.

e.g.

```
function Double(n)
 return 2*n
end

print(Double(arg[1]))
```

http://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html

Comment: update: Lua has exploded into many places, in many forms, and may even be emulated or plated-over in some cases, so be very careful and sure that your environment actually has arg. Some environments choose not to expose it, while others do. In cases where arg is unavailable, you can often fall back on arg = { ... } instead.  As usual, be sure to read your Lua environment's SPECIFIC documentation as they can vary greatly. A good place to start if you are unsure is the master of documents, a great place to start is with zeal! here: https://zealdocs.org

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `...` to get command line arguments:

```
local input = ...
if input then
  local Double
  Double = function(input)
    return 2 * input
  end
  return print(Double(input))
end
```